# Using a funcCall that retrieves multiple fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validation-engine

Ello, I'm using [jQuery-Validation-Engine](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/) and i don't know if this is currently possible but, Is there a way for you to possibly use the funcCall in a senario such as this.

I have to check a date range using 2 textboxes. I want to bind funcCall[dateRangeCheck] in such a way that I can get access 
to 2 fields as opposed to just the one. The end result would would something like this.

```
dateRangeCheck = function (fields, rules, i, options) {
    if (isDate(fields[0]) && isDate(fields[1])) {
        if (!dateCompare(fields[0], fields[1])) {
         return "* Invalid Date Range";
        }
    }
 };
```

Or possibly all the fields that a utilizing this particular funcCall like this

```
dateRangeCheck = function (fields, rules, i, options) {
    for (var i=0;i<fields.length;i++)
       if(!isDate(fields[i]){
          return "* Invalid Date Range";
       }
    }
 };
```

Is there some way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well now jQuery-validation-engine does support date range checking. Just made the commit myself waiting for it to be reviewed. lol, But no to that second example as of now.

[Here is the source. Have a nice day.](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine)

### Update

The latest version does support group validation.